# Docking a CControlBar derived window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

How can I dock a CControlBar derived window to the middle of a splitter window (CSplitterWnd)?  I would like the bar to be repositioned whenever the splitter is moved.

To make it a little clearer as to what I'm after, imagine the vertical ruler in the Dialog Editor in Visual Studio (MFC only).  It gets repositioned whenever the tree view is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alf,

In case of VS, there's no splitter used:
The resource view is a resizable ControlBar (It looks and feels like a splitter but it isn't a CSplitterWnd).
The rest is a child frame (either tabbed or MDI. Go to Tools/Options/Environment/General and choose Multiple Documents to convince yourself). The ruler is part (controlbar?) of the child frame.

In your case, I think you don't want a 3 panes splitter. You need a 2 pane splitter and the control bar should be part of your view (it wouldn't be a CControlBar per se). Unless you use MDI in which case you can make it a true ControlBar in your child frame.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Serge,
I apologize, I wasn't very clear.  The splitter would be between the resource view and the ruler bar.  It would looke like this:

Resource View | Vertical ruler | View

In any case, I found the (now obvious) answer: split the main frame into three windows:

```
m_wndSplitter.CreateStatic(this, 1, 3);

m_wndLeftPane.Create(&m_wndSplitter,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,m_wndSplitter.IdFromRowCol(0, 0));
m_ruler.Create(&m_wndSplitter,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,m_wndSplitter.IdFromRowCol(0, 1));

m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 2, pContext->m_pNewViewClass, CSize(300, 0), pContext);
SetActiveView((CScrollView*)m_wndSplitter.GetDlgItem(m_wndSplitter.IdFromRowCol(0, 2)));
```